# IPython: How can I run a script, enter an interactive session, and run "whos()" using only startup options/flags?

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-magic

I'd like to be able to **both** start an interactive session after completing a script (which I know can be done with `ipython -i myscript.py`), **and** have the shell execute the `whos()` command immediately afterward. This will help my workflow by allowing my to try out a script, and if there are errors, pick out suspect variables in the namespace to see what their deal is (it's often hard to remember exactly which variable is called what).

Is this even possible? I tried `ipython -c "whos" -i myscript.py`, but it seems ipython will only run the `-i` part or `-c` part -- whichever comes first.

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, this can be done using `%run` magic and the literal Enter character:

```
ipython -i -c "%run myfile^M%whos"
```

where `myfile` is the script head (no `.py`), and `^M` is obtained in the shell by typing <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.